# sqlite query in iphone causes leak

Tags: iphone, cocoa, memory-leaks, sqlite

I would like to know if calling a method in the following format is any reason for LEAKS?

```
[userLookupWS initWithUsername:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_system, 2)] andPassword:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_system, 3)] andURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_system, 0)], [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_system, 1)]] andSSL:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(select_system, 4)]];
```

What is the other way round to pass parameters to this method as I am getting 100% memory leak in this statement!

Regards, 
Accilies

Comment: What exactly does leak? The userLookupWS instance maybe? Then you're not releasing it and it's not the fault of SQLite related stuff. Where do you alloc?

Comment: Use [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Comment: I think the information is not enough. From this line code, I only know the userLookupWS which doesn't be deallocated finally, so it makes memory leak.

Comment: i do release the object after my code and from Peter's answer, I am getting the leak reduced. However, I have added comment which can be referred below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you sending `initWithUsername:` to an object stored in a variable? You should be passing the result of alloc there directly (`userLookupWS = [[SomeClass alloc] initWithUsername:…]`), and don't ever re-initialize an existing instance.

Aside from just being strange (it's initialized already! Why are you initializing it again?), nearly all `init…` methods are written for the assumption that they'll only be called once per instance, so sending an `initWithWhatever:` message to an already-initialized instance will leak everything that that instance owns.

There is no good way to fix that except to simply not do that in the first place. Don't send any `init` message to an already-initialized instance. The easiest way to avoid this is to only send an `init` message directly to the return value of `alloc` (`[[SomeClass alloc] init…]`).

And, of course, anything `alloc` returns, you have to release. The easiest way to ensure that happens is to autorelease the object immediately: `[[[SomeClass alloc] init…] autorelease]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter. That makes sense.. I followed the step as explained and it did reduce the memory leak from 100% on that line to 9%. Now investigating further into this, I found that i am getting the leak from CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux instead. Which i believe is from the inline assignment of NSSTRING in my code.. [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@"... do you think i should assign them separately and then release it over ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking me. That isn't an assignment. Is it the string that's being leaked, or something else allocated by `CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter, what i mean to ask is that from my piece of code, should i do NSSTRING *AA = [[NSSTRING ALLOC] INITWITHFORMAT...] and then then use this AA as follows:
[userLookupWS initWithUsername:AA... etc will this make any difference in the memory leaking issue with NSSTRING?

Comment: Why are you writing code in all caps? Use inline code formatting syntax if you want to distinguish it from human-language text. Anyway: The only thing that affects whether you leak, crash, or are doing it right is whether you obey the memory management rules: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/ Using `alloc`/`initWithFormat:` doesn't help (and can hurt if you forget to release), and assigning to a local variable makes no difference.

Comment: Hello Peter, I am not aware of the inline code formatting available this comment box... would like to know though ! Regarding the memory management, I will go through the link and try to resolve that issue. Thanks for the help though and appreciate if you can let me know the inline coding format to use...

Comment: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax You can use any inline element (such as inline code font). You can only use block elements (such as code blocks) in question and answers, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The initxxx method name suggest that an object is returned that is your responsibility to free, so yes if you don't release that object you may get a memory leak.